Is MAX86150 or MAX30003 better for monitor the child's heart rate, oxygen levels (SpO2) and more?
I’m working on developing a wrist-worn smartwatch for kids. The device needs to monitor vital signs such as heart rate, oxygen saturation (SpO2), and potentially distress-related changes like arrhythmias or hypoxia.

Which sensor is better for smartwatch?
Would the MAX86150 with its multi-modal capabilities (PPG, ECG, and BIA) be more effective in providing a comprehensive picture, or would the MAX30003's dedicated ECG offer more accurate heart rate data for detecting distress?

Would the ECG from MAX86150 be sufficient for detecting distress in scenarios, or would the MAX30003 provide more reliable ECG data?

What other sensors or considerations should I take into account to improve the detection accuracy, such as motion sensors (e.g., accelerometers) or water detection?


I’d appreciate any insights or suggestions based on your experience with similar wearable health monitoring or safety devices.

Please [edit] to add datasheet links for the devices. Can you identify the specifications that are causing you confusion? Give page / paragraph / table references.

First, you need to understand that an ECG can not be obtained passively from a wrist-worn smartwatch. An ECG requires two electrical contacts from opposite sides of the heart -- often the left and right arms in the simplest configuration. Smartwatches that measure ECG require the wearer to touch a contact point on the watch with a fingertip from the arm opposite the one wearing the watch. This doesn't seem practical for detecting distress in a child.
Based on this the design should use PPG. It could include ECG as an option if the child is in a position to cooperate -- e.g., early stage of an asthma attack and similar situations.
Regarding all the risks that children face, the scope of that question is too large to address here.
